# Direct limit of strict henselizations

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology

Assume we have a map $A \rightarrow A'$ of strictly henselian local rings, such that the induced map between spectra $S'\rightarrow S$ is essentially smooth. Is is true that $S'$ is a direct limit of strict henselizations at geometric points on the closed fiber of an affine scheme smooth over $S$?

Comment: If $S'$ is smooth over $S$, then $A'$ is finitely presented over $A$.  Every finitely presented local homomorphism is finite.  Thus, $A'$ is finite and 'etale over $A$.  Did you want to assume that $S'$ is "formally smooth" over $S$, or maybe "essentially smooth" over $S$?

Comment: @JasonStarr I am trying to make sense of a certain remark in a document available at https://virtualmath1.stanford.edu/~conrad/Weil2seminar/Notes/L7-8.pdf "By the compatibility of cohomology with direct limits (for
qcqs schemes), it suffices to treat the case when S'
is the strict
henselization at a geometric point on the closed fiber of an
affine scheme T that is smooth over S (since the coordinate
ring for S' at the end of the preceding step is a direct limit of
such strict henselizations)." (page 12)

Comment: In the proof of the smooth base change theorem, to prove that the induced map of sheaves is an isomorphism, it suffices to check that the induced maps of stalks are each isomorphisms.  For the etale topology, the stalk is computed by base change to a strictly Henselian local ring.  However, that does not mean that the local homomorphism is smooth.  It is not smooth, because it is not locally finitely presented.  However, it is "essentially smooth".

Comment: As darx points out, I should have written "formally smooth" in the last line of my previous comment.  Anyway, I do not see any mistake in the note that you link.  Stalks are convenient for proving properties of finite type $k$-schemes and finite type morphisms, even though local rings are rarely finite type $k$-algebras, and local homomorphisms of local rings are rarely finite type homomorphisms.

Answer (score 2):

We will be using the following definitions which I think are the definitions most often used in the literature.

A ring map $A \to B$ is called *essentially smooth* if there is a smooth ring map $A \to C$ and a multiplicative subset $S \subset C$ such that $B$ is isomorphic to $S^{-1}C$ as an $A$-algebra. Not everybody agrees with this definition so you should be careful when you read a paper or a book!

A morphism of schemes $f : X \to Y$ is called *essentially smooth* if there exists an affine open covering $Y = \bigcup V_j$ and for each $j$ an affine open covering $f^{-1}(V_j) = \bigcup U_{ij}$ such that the ring maps $H^0(V_j, \mathcal{O}_{V_j}) \to H^0(U_{ij}, \mathcal{O}_{U_{ij}})$ are essentially smooth. Not everybody agrees with this definition, so you should be careful when you read a paper or a book.

Now if $X$ is a local scheme and $Y$ is affine, then it follows (by a tiny argument) that $f$ is essentially smooth if and only if $H^0(Y, \mathcal{O}_Y) \to H^0(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ is essentially smooth. (I do not think this is true for general affine schemes.)

OK, so I think an honest translation of your question into a more precise language is: when is a local ring homomorphism $A \to B$ of strictly henselian local rings essentially smooth? I claim this happens if and only if $A = B$.

Aside: I understand from the discussion in the comments this is not at all what you are interested in, but it just occurred to me that it is a fun question with a (kinda) fun answer. Please don't edit the question, just ask a new one if you want to change your question.

Proof of the claim. If $A = B$, then clearly $A \to B$ is essentially smooth. Conversely, assume $A \to B$ is essentially smooth. If $A \to B$ has relative dimension $> 0$, then $R = B/\mathfrak m_A B$ is a local ring which is the localization of a smooth algebra over the field $\kappa = A/\mathfrak m_A$ and is strictly henselian (as a quotient of a strictly henselian local ring).

Fact: if $\dim(R) > 0$, then $R$ is not henselian. For example, let $t \in R$ be an element which is transcendental over $\kappa$ such that $t$ maps to $1$ in $R/\mathfrak m_R$. (We omit the proof that such an $t$ exists; here you have to use that $\dim(R) > 0$.) Choose a prime $\ell$ different from the characteristic of $\kappa$. Then if $R$ is henselian, it contains elements $u_n$ such that $u_n^{\ell^n} = t$ for all $n > 1$. Clearly, the field generated by $t, u_n$ in the fraction field of $R$ is not finitely generated over $\kappa$. Hence the fraction field of $R$ is not finitely generated over $\kappa$. Hence $R$ isn't the localization of any finite type $\kappa$-algebra, in particular $R$ isn't the localization of a smooth $\kappa$-algebra.

Since $\dim(R) = 0$ we see that $A \to B$ is essentially \'etale (because being \'etale is the same thing as being smooth of relative dimension $0$). Since $A$ is strictly henselian we get $A = B$ by one of the many characterizations of strictly henselian local rings.